# Cómo puedo evitar que mi código de Google Apps Script sea visible a los colaboradores

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-forms, google-documentos

He creado un proyecto vinculado (bounded) a una hoja de cálculo en Google Apps Script y estoy pensando en crear otros más en otras aplicaciones.

No quiero que los colaboradores de mis hojas de cálculo o de mi otros contenedores de apps scripts puedan visualizar el código de mis proyectos. Sólo quiero que puedan ejecutarlos.

Según entiendo de lo siguiente, publicar el código como una biblioteca (library) no ayuda ya que se requiere dar acceso de lectura para que esta sea agregada al proyecto y que pueda ser ejecutada.

De [Collaborating with Other Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/collaborating):

> Sharing and libraries
>
> Libraries included in your project are shared with project
>   collaborators. Though, if they do not have at least read-level access
>   to an included library they are unable to use those libraries and will
>   encounter an error if they attempt to do so. For more information
>   about libraries, see [Managing Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/managing_libraries).

¿Cómo puedo bloquear el acceso de visualización al código?

He consultado la documentación indicada en referencias pero no logro encontrar cómo bloquear la visualización del código a los colaboradores de los contenedores (hojas de cálculo, documentos, formularios).

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup>: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/
- <sup>2</sup>: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries

Comment: @FelipeCalvo Recién refraseé el segundo párrafo. Espero que con eso te parezca más claro a que se refiere la pregunta pero sobre todo una respuesta útil.

Comment: @César: Favor de ver http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/326/65

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

No es posible bloquear la visualización del código de proyectos de código vinculado (bounded scripts).

> Esto sigue vigente en Mayo de 2019.

## Respuesta amplia

Como se mencionó en la pregunta, el uso de bibliotecas (libraries) requiere de acceso al menos de lectura únicamente ya que de lo contrario al intentar ejecutar funciones que dependen de la biblioteca se mostrará un error. Las soluciones provisionales (workaround) podrían variar según el tipo y características del código. Por tipo me refiero a si se trata de una función de hoja de cálculo personalizada, usualmente llamada simplemente como función personalizada, una función que se activa mediante un menú o un evento.

Una alternativa es la creación de un complemento (add-on). Los detalles en [Develop Add-ons for Google Sheets, Documents and Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/).

Cabe destacar que los complementos se pueden restringir para ser usados por usuarios del mismo dominio que el desarrollador, se requiere <s>Google Apps for Work</s> G Suite. Para detalles, véase https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish.

Otra alternativa que podría funcionar en ciertos casos es la creación de una aplicación web que pueda llamarse desde la hoja de cálculo, por ejemplo, mediante un complemento como [Bloqkspring](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blockspring/aihldeahgcpbpmimkdpkafaedhbmfhoh?hl=es-MX).