# Como proteger que mi codigo se modifique

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Necesito garantizar que los usuarios con perfil de editor con quienes comparto la hoja google sheet "NO" puedan modifica mi codigo o agregar nuevo codigo

Comment: No tengo ni idea de eso, pero a mi entender, un perfil de **editor** es para que pueda editar, sea lo que sea, sino se llamaria de otra manera.  Si no quieres que lo hagan cambiales el perfil a **observador**, si es que existe y te lo permiten :-)  O quizás puedas aplicar un bloqueo general de cambios a la hoja de cálculo, pero si siguen siendo editores supongo que podran desbloquearlo y editarla igualmente.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus comentarios mi problema es que estoy compartiendo una hoja para trabajarla entre varias personas que tienen  campos protegidos según la persona, el problema que tengo es que para poder trabajar en la hoja tienen que tener perfil de editor y con eso ellos pueden mediante código alterar los niveles de protección o cambiar la data de campos que ellos estén restringido.

Comment: Diria que tienes que ceñirte a lo que dicen las instrucciones de google. En este [enlace](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?hl=es&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cproteger-un-intervalo-o-una-hoja%2Cqui%C3%A9n-puede-proteger-una-hoja-o-un-intervalo%2Ceditar-una-copia-de-una-hoja-protegida) encontrarás toda la información.  Si deseas algo más de lo que pone allí dudo que puedas hacerlo, lo siento.

Answer (score 1):

No es posible evitar que los editores agreguen nuevo código a una hoja de cálculo de Google. Tampoco es posible evitar que editen el código de un proyecto de Apps Script contenido en la hoja de cálculo.

Una opción es poner mayor parte del código en una librería ya que la librería se puede compartir con los editores de la hoja de cálculo con permiso de ver sólamente. Otra opción es crear un complemento.

Dependiendo de lo que haga tu código, una opción más podría ser usar un proyecto "stand-alone".

Relacionado

- [Cómo puedo evitar que mi código de Google Apps Script sea visible a los colaboradores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/47/65)